# Failed to start an activity with implicit intent and had added category in xml

Tags: android, android-intent

The logcat indicates that I have a `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Here's my code:

Java:

```
    Intent data=new Intent();
    data.setAction("com.example.exercise1.activity2");
    startActivity(data);
```

Manifest XML:

```
       <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity2" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.exercise1.activity2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
```

I've added the category in XML, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 remove code `<action android:name="com.example.exercise1.activity2" />`

2 change code `android:name=".Activity2"` to `android:name="com.example.exercise1.Activity2"`

Answer (score 0):

please refer to [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction%28java.lang.String%29)

Under implicit intents. I think you have to set your package name also in the Manifest tag.

Happy debugging!